# AngularJS: run function every so often

Tags: angularjs, controller

I need to run a function automatically every so often and I have no idea how to do it. Can you help me? Thank you!!

Comment: Use [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use $interval, executes the specified function on every specified millisecond's duration.

```
$scope.intervalFn= function () {
    console.log('test');
}

$interval($scope.intervalFn, 500);
```

See this docs,https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: Thank you Ankita Dobariya!

Comment: Happy to help you :)